# CentOS 73: how to ifup a NIC automatically?

Tags: centos, networking, hot-plug

In **CentOS 7.3**, without `Network Manager`, how do I ensure a NIC being `ifup` automatically?

I added `HOTPLUG=yes` in the `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1`, but when I **hotplug** the NIC, the NIC is not up in "`ifconfig`". (`ifconfig -a` will list it).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

OK, looks like in Redhat/centos, NM is the way to handle hotplug.
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/429653

Comment: You should also look into summarizing the article, because most people do not have access to the Red Hat solutions.

Answer (score 0):

In your config file (/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-), you can use the `ONBOOT=yes` option.